# Azure Active Directory: One user with multiple providers account

Tags: azure, active-directory, user-accounts

I'm developing a Azure Mobile App and I need help about Azure Active Directory. I'd like that the user can login with a Microsoft, Facebook or Google account. But if the user has two or more accounts of different providers, those accounts can be linked to the same user and the user can login with any of those accounts. Is it possible?

Comment: Hi, have you found any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the description, it seems you want to support the application can authenticate multiple consume identity provider. As far as I know, the B2C tenant do support this scenario.

> > But if the user has two or more accounts of different providers, those accounts can be linked to the same user and the user can login with any of those accounts

The B2C tenant doesn’t support this feature. However, we can complete it in our app. For example, after the users sign-in, you may require the users to bind the account to a unique id, and then in your app you can use this unique id to identify all the accounts the same user bind.

More detail about B2C tenant developing, you can refer [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-b2c-devquickstarts-web-dotnet/).

Comment: Hi Fei, when you're are saying we can do it through unique id, does it mean we will create unique id from app side and sore it to identify same user. In this case if user switch device what happens?